# Constructor for class with many attributes

Tags: python, constructor

What is the best approach to write a constructor when you have a class with many attributes?

For example in a college hw we were given a piece of code in which you have to explicitly set all attributes when you create the object. I noticed that some of them are used only once in the beginning/end. Therefore i created an equal code where i give some default values to rare-used attributes and set them outside the object creation only in the beginning/end.

I wanted to ask if this approach is recommended and if there is a general approach on how to make constructors for classes with many attributes.

Here is a simplified version of college code:

```
class point(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,bonus,start_point,stop_point):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.bonus = bonus
        self.start_point = start_point
        self.stop_point = stop_point

        #some more attributes


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #some code here

    p = point(1,1,100,False,False)

    #some code here
```

My version:

```
class point(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,bonus):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.bonus = bonus
        self.start_point = False
        self.stop_point = False

        #some more attributes


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #some code here

    p = point(1,1,100)

    #some code here

    #start/stop points are 1 in n (n=10000) in the original code
    #so set these attributes once in the beggining/end
    p.start_point = False
    p.stop_point = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a question of performance or "how often" it's used. It is a question of interface.

You have a class, and it provides interface for creating objects. Someone (maybe even you yourself) will use it to do something. The question is, is this attributes a part of object constructor? Does it make sense to provide this values while creating an object? Does it even make sense to give user an ability to set it from outside of object?

If it does make sense to set this attributes while creating, but it will mostly have same values, provide default values to parameter, but don't set it implicitly, because you still making them a part of public interface:

```
class point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, bonus, start_point=False, stop_point=False):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.bonus = bonus
        self.start_point = start_point
        self.stop_point = stop_point
```

this way you can omit this two arguments and you can provide it when you want. But good thing is that you giving users a hint of what you can set during creation.